# vim macro to convert current line to figlet

Tags: vim, macros, buffer, figlet

I wrote a macro to test calling it on a line to convert it to figlet *(text ascii-art version)*

I tryied working around something like

```
let @q='"add:r! figlet <c-r>a^M'
```

or

```
let @q='"add:r! figlet ^Ra^M'
```

and so on from the :help macro recommandations

I just can't find the good syntax for it

when I run it manually in session it works so I guess the issue is syntax only

```
a
toto
<esc>
qq
"add
:r! figlet ^Ra^M
q
k
@q
```

then got

```
| |_ ___ | |_ ___                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
| __/ _ \| __/ _ \                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
| || (_) | || (_) |                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 \__\___/ \__\___/
```

this is the similar result I need to write as a macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your macro is way too complicated.

Instead of all that deleting and inserting dance, you should use `:help :range!` directly to filter the current line:

```
:.!figlet<CR>
```

[image: figlet]

which simplifies your macro tremendously:

```
:let @q = ":.!figlet\<CR>"
```